# Renaming an added variable in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the first column is name of each state. And the last column is a categorical variable. I want to scale all the other columns except these two. And later I want to add the last column back to the data frame. Here's what I did-

```
data_new <- cbind( scale(data[,2:11], FALSE, apply(data[,2:11], 2, sd)), data[ ,c(12)])
```

When I get back the dataframe, the last column's name is gone (if you see the column with 4,4,4,1,3,2....).

```
         violcr   propcr    ympct   medinc  ymunemp subsabuse     gini ineqratio   school  bachdeg  
 [1,] 3.3178283 5.520019 14.91484 4.926599 5.926865  9.942629 24.34441  2.297458 7.420143 5.293805 4
 [2,] 4.9355995 4.794578 19.33284 8.132947 3.660475 13.367018 21.36148  1.773477 6.497878 6.542936 4
 [3,] 3.1043508 5.554588 15.76717 5.653173 4.779743 12.653053 23.92486  2.754263 5.925069 6.270668 4
 [4,] 3.7269288 5.798660 15.19722 4.672179 4.334980 10.167396 24.11929  2.767698 8.379425 4.943795 4
 [5,] 3.0748521 4.240596 16.55721 6.962185 5.279658 11.515997 25.01979  3.882839 5.351711 7.171495 1
 [6,] 2.3994870 4.395204 16.06272 6.731090 3.732236 13.591785 23.45414  2.700521 5.250990 8.690245 3
 [7,] 1.8390115 3.336054 15.09004 7.914420 5.419199 11.820093 25.60819  5.723492 7.062003 7.554442 2
```

I tried using this command to name the 12th column-

```
colnames(data_new)[,12] <- "guns"
```

However, I get an error. If I try to rename all columns including the last, then also it doesn't work. Could someone help on how to fix this?

Comment: You may need `data[12]` i.e `cbind( scale(data[,2:11], FALSE, apply(data[,2:11], 2, sd)), data[12])` because `data[,12]` convert it to a `vector` while `data[12]` is still a data.frame

Comment: Great..that worked. Thanks!

Comment: What is the error you get when you try the `colnames` command? You should be able to use `cbind(..., guns=data[ ,12])` to assign a name.

Comment: When I used colnames , I got this error- 'Error in colnames(data_new)[, 12] <- "guns" : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix'. Anyway, I took akrun's suggestion and that helped

Comment: `colnames(data_new)` is a vector and not a matrix. so you need to talk of `colnames(data_new)[12]="given name"` and not `[,12]`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
colnames(data_new) <- c(colnames(data_new)[1:11], "guns")
```

what you do is create a new vector and then assign it. I think the col selector `data_new[,n]` gets you a subset of the data (i.e. one col n), but it's not helpful with headings